# How can we synchronise Database from Local to Web Server through Phpmyadmin database

Tags: django, database-design, django-models, phpmyadmin

I have a project working on my local system . Which is a django(1.4.1) Python project using Phpmyadmin as database . As per completetion of modules i updated into server . Is there any way to sync database from Local to Server through Phpmyadmin database .

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have got *Synchronization* feature with phpmyadmin.

For details you may check [this link](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/Documentation.html#faqsynchronization)